# SquareSpace Bedford - Change logo per page, add text out of page, something

Tags: jquery, html, css, squarespace

my client's last request on this project is that I add the word "HOME" under the logo on 2 of 3 pages. If it was all 3 i'd edit the logo and we'd be done, but she wants it only on the pages that aren't the home page.

I already have the banner description text acting as a title for the pages. I thought if I could get the actual page title text to show I could use that, resize it down and move it with CSS but that hasn't proven simple.

I've tried a code block in the first page of the index, though I can't move the text higher then the block with CSS :c

Even if I could just get it to load a different logo on the two other pages.

sharay.squarespace.com is the website in question.

Cheers for any insight on this guys.

Answer (score 0):

I would detect the homepage using something like this jQuery:

```
var page = window.location.pathname;
if(page == '/' || page == '/home-page-url'){
    $(".logo").attr("src", "/path/to-logo/without-home");
} else {
    $(".logo").attr("src", "/path/to-logo/with-home");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this can be done using only CSS, inserted via the [CSS Editor](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545567-Using-the-CSS-Editor). The Bedford template (as many other templates) apply a class of `homepage` to the `body` element of the home page, so one can use that to differentiate between home and 'non-home' pages.

From there, it's just a case of adding text via the CSS 'content' property. You can of course modify the styles I've suggested below.

```
body:not(.homepage) #logoImage a:after {
  content: "Home";
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

See attached image for the result of this code when used on the website you provided. Using this, you would remove the "HOME" text added to the image itself.

[image]